# Can't figure out how to join sql tables back together to create a report

Tags: sql, t-sql, report

I can't share actual company data, so please bear with my simplified example with the same structure.

We have a system that keeps track of packages in an MS SQL database. Each package contains 1-3 boxes. All packages have at least one box, "BoxSide". Additionally, they might also have a "BoxOuter" next to it, and that box optionally might have "BoxInner" inside of it. Each box has contents that we keep the data on.

So there are five separate tables total: One with the package information, one for each box (Side, Outer and Inner) and one table that has the data about the contents of each. They relate to each other as shown in the following diagram:

[Table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdNvr.jpg)

What I want to do is run a query that puts all of that data together in a report with a single record for each package and fields for the contents of each box, leaving non-applicable fields blank. Something like:

Package.*, BoxSide.Data1, Boxside.Data2, BoxOuter.Data1, BoxOuter.Data2, BoxInner.Data1, BoxInner.Data2

To reiterate:

- I want a single record for every package
- Every Package has a BoxSide
- A Package MIGHT have a BoxOuter
- A BoxOuter MIGHT have a BoxInner

I've tried various joins to link this data back together, but I seem to always end up with missing packages (if they didn't have a certain box type) or duplicate records of the same package multiple times for different box types. Too many failed attempts to list here.

Can somebody with some SQL-fu please help me with a query that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` to get every record in `Package` regardless if it has corresponding values in the other tables:

```sql
    SELECT P.ID, p.Time, P.Type, P.Name, P.location,
    s.ID, sc.ID, sc.Data1, sc.Data2,sc.Data3
    o.ID, oc.ID, oc.Data1, oc.Data2, oc.Data3
    i.ID, ic.ID, ic.Data1, ic.Data2, ic.Data3
    FROM Package p
    LEFT JOIN BoxSide s ON p.ID = s.PackageID
    LEFT JOIN Contents sc ON s.ID = sc.ParentID
    LEFT JOIN BoxOuter o ON p.ID = o.PackageID
    LEFT JOIN Contents oc ON o.ID = oc.ParentID
    LEFT JOIN BoxInner i ON o.ID = i.BoxOuterID
    LEFT JOIN Contents ic ON i.ID = ic.ParentID
```

Note that you also have to `LEFT JOIN` the `Contents` table multiple times, each time with a different alias to link it to each parent table.

Comment: By Jove, I think you've got it. I've been tied up in meeting most of the day so far, but just gave this a whirl and got what look like plausible results. I've gotta review the data to make sure though.

Comment: @JJohnson. Great. If it turns out that this works for you, perhaps you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: So far all looks good! Even if I find something minor after more review, I now have a really great point to tinker from. So... solved!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying Left Joins on BoxOuter and BoxInner? This should return you Packages regardless of whether or not there are matches on the right.

```
SELECT Package.*,
       bsc.Data1,
       bsc.Data2,
       boc.Data1,
       boc.Data2,
       bic.Data1,
       bic.Data2
FROM Package p
INNER JOIN BoxSide bs ON p.id = bs.packageid
LEFT JOIN BoxOuter bo ON p.id = bo.packageid
LEFT JOIN BoxInner bi ON bo.id = bi.boxouterid
INNER JOIN Contents bsc ON bs.id = bsc.parentid
INNER JOIN Contents boc ON bo.id = boc.parentid
INNER JOIN Contents bic ON bi.id = bic.parentid
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
I think we are on the right track here, but the Data1 and Data2 fields are actually in the separate Contents table in the diagram, not part of the Box tables themselves (sorry if my list for desired report items was misleading!)
How would I go about joining that table into the mix?

Comment: Is there always a Contents row for each Box row? We should be able to modify the query to apply a join for each Box table to the Content table

Comment: @JJohnson Did you have a look at the answer I offered? it brings in the `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data3` fields from the `Contents` table for each "box" type. It uses `LEFT JOIN` for each table to assure that you get every `Package` record regardless if there are records in any of the sub tables. If it doesn't work for you, please let me know why.